# Error witht the R code when executing. Is there a missing parameter?

Tags: r

I am getting an error in my R code below:

```
**Part of the code with the error:**
anchor <- getNodeSet(doc, "//a")
anchor <- sapply(anchor, function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "href"))
```

**Error message**:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Comment: try  `sapply(anchor, xmlGetAttr, "href")`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly does `doc` contain? Or what exactly does `getNodeSet(doc, "//a")` return? What packages are you using?